# Select an item from database and populate Form with data of that specific selection with PHP JavaScript and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

Please, I am stuck with this for a while. I have been trying to use PHP, Javascript and Ajax to create a drop down selection with existing authors from my database. In this list 'onChange' author selection I would like to populate values of a form with the data of that specific selected author, but I can't find a way to that. Hope u guys can understand what I am trying to achive. Thank you!!

I have a select/options drop down list populated with Author Names from the database:

```
<?php // foreach - authors from the database for the drop down select list.
  function getAuthor() {
       $sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT AuthorID, Name, Surname FROM author');
       $sth->execute();
       $result = $sth-> fetchAll();
          foreach( $result as $row ) {
          echo '<option>' . $row["Name"] . '</option>';
        }
 }
?>

<form>    
<fieldset>
<label>Existing author?</label> 
<select onChange="myFunction(this.value)" id="sel"> onChange calling js function.
          <option>Select Author</option>
          <?php getAuthor();?>
</select>

<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" name='name' autocomplete="off" value="<?php   ?>" required>

<label>Surname:</label>
<input type="text" name='surname' autocomplete="off" value="<?php  ?>" required>

<label>Nationality:</label>
<input type="text" name='nationality' autocomplete="off" value="<?php  ?>" required>

 </fieldset>

<input type="hidden" name="action_type" value="add">
<input id="btnaddbook" value="ADD BOOK AND AUTHOR" type="submit">
</form>
```

Javascript // Selected value from the authors list and sending with Ajax. I am trying to use 'onChange' to send values for every selection change.

```
function myFunction() {
   var authors = document.getElementById("sel").value;

var data = new XMLHttpRequest();
    data.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (data.readyState == 4 && data.status == 200) {
            document.innerHTML = data.responseText;
        }
    };
    data.open("POST", "../pages/addbook.php", true);
    data.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    data.send("mydata="+authors);

}
```

PHP receiving Ajax.

```
<?php
require ("../../model/db.php");

if(isset($_POST['mydata'])){

    $sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT AuthorID, Name FROM author WHERE author.AuthorID  =' . $_POST['mydata']);
    $sth->execute();
    $row =  $sth->fetch();    
}
```

Comment: Use `echo $row['Name'];`. It will not solve, but it's a step for your understanding. Javascript will display the data from your PHP, so you need to send it back to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, thank you!
I am posting here in case anyone else is having a very hard time with php/javascript/ajax, just like me. I found really hard to understand other examples, I will try to make it simple and I hope it helps someone else. I wish I had found an explanation like this hahaha!!! 
Not sure if it was the best way, but it is working.

**Get data from database and display as a selecting list**.

```
 <?php
        function getAuthor() {
        require ("../../model/db.php"); // need the connection with the database..

        $output = '';

        $sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT AuthorID, Name FROM author');

        $sth->execute();
        $result = $sth-> fetchAll();

        foreach( $result as $row ) { // output authorid as a value for the selection
        // echo authorid as the input value=" "    
        $output .= '<option value="'.$row['AuthorID'].'">'.$row['Name'].'</option>';

           }
         echo $output;
    }
?>
```

**HTML FORM with php getAuthor() to displays existing authors in the DB.**  **onchange="myfunction(this.value)" to send id to JavaScript on every change selection.**

```
<h1>Add Author</h1>

    <fieldset> 
    <label>Existing author?</label>
        <select onchange="myFunction(this.value)"> // sending selected id to javascript.
            <option>Select Author</option>
            <?php getAuthor();?>
        </select>

    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name='name' id="aname" value="" autocomplete="off"  required>


    <label>Surname:</label>
    <input type="text" name='surname' id=asurname value=""  autocomplete="off" required>

    <label>Nationality:</label>
    <input type="text" name='nationality' id="anationality"  value="" autocomplete="off"  required>

    <label>Birth Year:</label>
    <input type="number" name='birthyear' id="abirthday"  value="" autocomplete="off" required>

    <label>Death Year:</label>
    <input type="number" name='deathyear' id="adeath" value="" autocomplete="off" >
    </fieldset>

    <input type="hidden" name="action_type" value="add">
    <input id="btnaddbook" value="ADD BOOK AND AUTHOR" type="submit">
    </div>
    </form>
```

**JavaScript/Ajax, Receiving id from selected option, posting id to website service with AJAX and receiving data from webservice according to the posted id.**

```
   function myFunction(authors) {

    var result = {};

    var data = new XMLHttpRequest();
    data.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (data.readyState === 4 && data.status === 200) {
            result = JSON.parse(data.responseText); // receiving response from web service and populating from input values with data from the database.

            document.getElementById("aname").value = result.aname;
            document.getElementById("asurname").value = result.asurname;
            document.getElementById("anationality").value = result.anationality;
            document.getElementById("abirthday").value = result.abirthday;
            document.getElementById("adeath").value = result.adeath;
        }
    };
    data.open("POST", "../../controller/webservice.php", true);
    data.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    data.send("id="+authors);

}
```

**Web service receiving posted id from AJAX, selecting data from DB according to the posted id and sending data to be display on the html form as an array using json_encode() function.**

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");

require ("../model/db.php");

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
  if(!empty($_POST['id'])) {
    $sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT AuthorID, Name, Surname, Nationality, BirthYear, DeathYear FROM author WHERE author.AuthorID  =' . $_POST['id']); // $_POST['id'] = ajax posted id.
    $sth->execute();
    $result =  $sth->fetchAll();    
    foreach($result as $row){

        $myArray = array("aname" => $row['Name'], "asurname" => $row['Surname'], "anationality" => $row['Nationality'], "abirthday" => $row['BirthYear'], "adeath" => $row['DeathYear']);

    }
        echo json_encode($myArray);

    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)**

You don't need this part of your code `var authors = document.getElementById("sel").value;`. You're passing a value while calling the function `onChange="myFunction(this.value)"`. Just change your function signature from `function myFunction()` to e.g. `function myFunction(author)`. Now you can use just `author`.

**2)**

It's `onchange` not `onChange`.

**3)**

`<option>` tag needs a value. You just give it something like a label (author's name). In the end, your select every time has no value.

**4)**

Homework: Read about Prepared Statements (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) because your current code is SQL Injection vulnerable.

I think it will work after these changes. If not feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: Hey, appreciate your time on answering my question. 
I made the changes according to what you have said and after you said the option tag needs a value you got me to find a solution!!! The <OPTION> TAG needed the author ID from my database as a value, then I was able to get id and send POST through AJAX to the server. On my server I did the query SELECT AuthorID FROM authors WHERE AuthorID = ' . $_POST['id'].

Thank you.